# Angular *ngFor not displaying data

Tags: angular

I'm doing an Angular course and got this issue - `*ngFor` is not displaying data from array.

My files looks like this:

Model class in `recipe.model.ts`:

```
export class Recipe {
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
    public imagePath: string;

    constructor(name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = desc;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

My component `recipe-list.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-list',
  templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-list.component.css']
})
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  recipes: Recipe[] = [new Recipe('test recipe', 'test', '01.jpg')];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

And `recipe-list.component.html`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
      </div>
      <span class="pull-right">
        <img [src]="recipe.imagePath" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px;">
      </span>
    </a>
    <app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is my app doesn't display data at pools where data binding is used

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
```

When I switch it to some static data like this:

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Pizza</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">Best Pizza</p>
```

it works ok and data is displayed.

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Is it a wrong `*ngFor` use / implementation? Wrong class exports/imports? I checked and it looked ok.

Comment: I tried your code on stackblitz, it's working. Only issue was extra ```</div>``` on third line.

Comment: i was comparing my code to instructor's code from video for 2h and everything was the same, it works also in his screen so the problem must be somewhere else. When i insepct elements i have this error in console - maybe this is the issue? 
ERROR InternalError: too much recursion
    Angular 128
core.mjs:7643:22
InternalError: too much recursion
    Angular 128

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: could you please provide `app-recipe-item` code? my guess is the error is there

Comment: i checked this before providing here and you were right! unnecessary selector was there, dont know how and when i put it there. After deleting all errors are gone from console and databinding works perfectly ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with CSS.
Try Inspecting and check whether the data is displayed.

I tried your code and it worked for me. Below is the link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pp1dq3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i was afraid of this answer becouse it means the problem is probably somewhere else. I use VSC, got this errors when inspect elenets: ERROR InternalError: too much recursion
    Angular 128
core.mjs:7643:22
InternalError: too much recursion
    Angular 128